# Rendering nested json data with axios.get in react

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, axios

I am new to react.js and I am trying to fetch server side data in JSON format in a html element. So what I did in frontend is:

```
export class Product extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> {
state = {
    cols : '',
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://example.com/product/5`)
        .then(res => {
        const tech_specs = JSON.parse(res.data.specification);
        var cols = '';
        for(var tech_specs_category in tech_specs) {
            var rows = '';
            for (var spec_title in tech_specs[tech_specs_category]){
                var tech_specs_value = tech_specs[tech_specs_category][spec_title];
                rows += '<li><span class="spec">' + spec_title + '</span><span class="value">' + tech_specs_value + '</span></li>'
            }
            cols += '<div class="spec_title"><span>&#9679; ' + tech_specs_category + '</span></div>' + '<ul>' + rows + '</ul>'
        }
        this.setState({ cols });
        })
}
public render() {
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.cols}}/>
}
```

and JSON that server side (backend) API gives me:

```
{"specification":"{\"مشخصات کلی\":{\"تعداد سیم کارت(عدد)\":\"2\",\"تعداد سیم کارت\":\"دو سیم کارت\",\"ابعاد(میلیمتر)\":\"7 × 76.4 × 156.4\",\"وزن(گرم)\":\"165\",\"قطع سیم کارت\":\"سایز نانو\",\"جنس بدنه\":\"\",\"ضد آب\":\"FALSE\",\"تاریخ انتشار\":\"2016, September\"},\"null\":{\"قیمت\":\"\"}}
```

this code gives me what I wanted but I know this is vulnerable to xss.
How can I do this in safe way?

Comment: Instead of building a string that you set in state and render with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, you could just set the data as is in the state, and derive the JSX from the state in the render method.

Comment: *this code gives me what I wanted but I know this is vulnerable to xss.* - if it's your backend, how is it possible? It should be sanitized, of course. It's unclear whether JSON is expected to contain HTML or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dangerouslySetInnerHTML attribute is just for reminding developers not to use InnerHTML for getting inputs from use which may cause XSS attacks. so in my example it's safe to use this method.